# If 1 rak'ah of fazr salat is done within the waqt, then will the salat be acceptable?

Tags: salat

Well, we all know that salat must be performed within the waqt (specified time span).

Now I heard once that if 1 rak'ah of the obligatory fazr salah (2 rak'ah) is performed within the waqt, that is, before the sunrise, then the whole 2 rak'ah will be counted as being performed within the waqt.

Is this true and are there any sources supporting this claim?

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is true

Comment: @AsanRamzan Could u cite some references pls, Assalamualikum

Comment: Well, I'd remember reading it in BUKHARI so had to search though it and found it:Volume 1, Book 10, Number 531 :

Comment: @AsanRamzan If u post this as an answer, you'll get reputation, why not do that? Zazakallahu khairan !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true I remember reading it in BUKHARI, and I have found the reference:

Volume 1, Book 10, Number 531 :

Narrated by Abu Huraira

Allah's Apostle said, "If anyone of you can get one Rak'a of the 'Asr prayer before sunset, he should complete his prayer. If any of you can get one Rak'a of the Fajr prayer before sunrise, he should complete his prayer."